# jquery Animate() not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, css

I have an animation that is working fine in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox. My jquery code is

**Html**

```
<ul id="clientlist">
    <li name="clientitem0" class="clientitem">
        <div id="client0" class="client shadow">
            <img src="images/work/bbc.jpg" border=0>
            <p>National BBC</p>
            <a href="bbc.co.uk">
                <div class="website"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Script**

```
$("li[name^='clientitem']").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(200*index).fadeIn();
    $("#client"+index).delay(200*index).animate({"top": "0px"}, "slow");
});
```

**Css**

```
.client {
    position: relative; 
    top: 50px; 
    border: 1px solid #303234;
    background: #181B1D;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s linear;
}
```

Comment: whats not working on it in firefox?

Comment: As `Sheikh Heera` pointed out, can you please post the relevant html. If in future another user has similar issues and your posted link is dead or the site has changed the question becomes redundant.

Comment: <ul id="clientlist">
             <li name="clientitem0" class="clientitem"><div id="client0" class="client shadow"><img src="images/work/bbc.jpg" border=0><p>National BBC</p><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk"><div class="website"></div></a></div></li></ul>

Comment: Using the posted code and isolating it in a fiddle it behaves the same in Chrome (20.0.1132.57 m) and Firefox (13.0.1). Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HY4Cp/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added `transition` effect for `webkit` engine browsers(e.g. `Safari`,`Chrome`,etc...). You need to add similar thing for the other engines either:

```
.client {
    position: relative; 
    top: 50px; 
    border: 1px solid #303234;
    background: #181B1D;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s linear; 
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.2s linear;  
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.2s linear;  
    transition: transform 0.2s linear; 
}
```

Comment: may i ask why we need to add similar thing for other engines ?

Comment: OP mentioned `not working in Firefox` that means problem is browser specific and code is working and he used `-webkit-transition` that means `-moz-transition` could solve the problem for `Firefox`.

Comment: @Mayankswami Browsers use different rendering engines: `Safari&Chrome`-> `Webkit`, `Mozilla`->`Gecko`, etc...And if it specified `-webkit` then it works only in `webkit` engine browser

Comment: Hi I have made the change you suggested to the css, but it is still jumping compared to the smooth motion in safari and chrome (you can see it online now). Any other suggestions?

Comment: The main jumping was because I needed to set overflow to hidden for firefox only. This has made it animate up now on firefox, but I am getting very small jitter at the top on all browsers now. Any ideas?